# How to echo back database data for an AJAX request?

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to return some data from the database in a php file:

```
    $selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM admin_upload_macro";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($selectSQL);
    $stmt->execute();
    $files = array();
    while($abc = $stmt->fetch())
    {
        array_push($files, $abc);
    }
    echo var_dump($files);
```

However, this gives it back in a string format. How may I send back this data to the front-end in an iterable form?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

```
echo json_encode($files);
```